# How to find the total line number in xls file, but the file has some empty lines in between proper rows?

Tags: java

I have a test case to get the total lines present in the xls file using selenium, But i had a empty lines in between some lines how to get the total lines which is not empty?

Please refer below mentioned image for more details:

[image]

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

```
public int getRecordsCountInBudgetingReport(String FileName) {
        String downloadPath = "path";
        int lineNumberCount = 0;
        try {
            if (!FileName.isEmpty() || FileName != null) {
                String filePath =   downloadPath + System.getProperty("file.separator") + FileName;
                System.out.println(filePath);
                File file = new File(filePath);

                if (file.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("File found :" +FileName);
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

                    LineNumberReader linenumberreader = new LineNumberReader(fr);
                    //linenumberreader.
                    while (linenumberreader.readLine() != null) {
                        lineNumberCount++;
                    }
                    //To remove the header
                    lineNumberCount=lineNumberCount-3;
                linenumberreader.close();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File does not exists");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lineNumberCount;
    }
```

Comment: Selenium is not for reading xls files.

Comment: But We can perform the testing with "linenumberreader" . But i am not able find the proper count.

Comment: First of all, a spreadshit has **rows**, not lines. And the number of rows could be **different** for different columns. So you first get your requirements straight. And then you put up a [mcve]. Anything else will not work; we can't help with code that you are not sharing with us.

Comment: `linenumberreader` has nothing to do with Selenium. You should also post your code.

Comment: Please find my code above.

Comment: as a suggestion. look at a cells in a row. if you find a cell with content, increase a counter by 1. if there is no content, ignore it. it can be done with 2 for loops if you use apache poi. sadly i can't tell you how to do it properly in selenium. is it a csv or a xls file? in question i talk about xls but in code you write csv

Comment: You should work with a library able to read xls files, like Apache POI, not with text readers otherwise you can't get any valuable result